# An example of pratical application of Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle

I have looked into the Isabelle tutorial which presents an example of it's use in verifying security protocol. However, it is a bit out of my understanding as I only know the basics. I'm looking for some examples which are not just simple theorems but practical applications using Isabelle/HOL. 
For example proving some algorithms or may be verifying properties system or some non-trivial mathematical theorem. Are such examples available anywhere ?

I have looked into the list of all applications provided in the isabelle official page but most of them are proofs of theorems.

I am also looking at an example of a file system verification using Alloy. It provides a proof where the properties of file/directories can be verified. I'm looking for something similar to it.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://afp.sourceforge.net/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few highly non-trivial examples I can think of right now are:

- [seL4](https://sel4.systems/), an entire operating system kernel written in C that was verified with Isabelle.
- The AFP entry [Jinja_Threads](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/JinjaThreads.html) contains, as far as I know, a fully formalised bytecode compiler for a Java-like language with arrays and threads.
- Jeremy Avigad's proof of the [Prime Number Theorem](http://repository.cmu.edu/philosophy/31/).
- The proof of [Kepler's conjecture](https://code.google.com/p/flyspeck/). A part of this was done in Isabelle; most of it, however, was done in the more ‘basic’ theorem prover HOL Light, whose logic is similar to Isabelle.

As Joachim mentioned, I am sure you can find more interesting applications in the [AFP](http://afp.sourceforge.net/topics.shtml)

Comment: Thank you so much. I found a paper for Verifying a Hotel Key Card System. It's awesome ! http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/HotelKeyCards.shtml